# Query where table has multiple values for a column and the same value in another?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table that looks like this:

```
-------------------------
| id  | areaID | itemID |
-------------------------
| 1   | 7      | 3      |
-------------------------
| 2   | 7      | 4      |
-------------------------
| 3   | 8      | 3      |
-------------------------
| 4   | 10     | 4      |
-------------------------
```

Which signifies that area 7 has items 3 and 4, area 8 only has item 3, and area 10 has item 4 but no other items.

**How would I query for areaIDs that have both items 3 and 4?** In the case of the above table, only areaID 7 will be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just want `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT areaID
FROM table t
WHERE itemID IN (3,4)
GROUP BY areaID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT itemID) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach by using sum to verify each `itemID` should exist

```
select areaID
from demo
where itemID in(3,4)
group by areaID
having sum(itemID = 3) >0 
and sum(itemID = 4) > 0 ;
```

Or by using `exists`

```
select distinct areaid
from demo a
where exists (
      select 1
      from  demo
      where itemid = 3 and areaid = a.areaid
) and (
      select 1
      from  demo
      where itemid = 4  and areaid = a.areaid
)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/971d50/7)

Answer (score 0):

Use group by

```
select areaID from table1 
where itemID in (3, 4) 
group by areaID
having count(distinct itemID) = 2
```

Comment: This answer was given by two other users 5 minutes before you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

This should give the result: areaID = 7

```
SELECT areaID
FROM table t
WHERE itemId in (3,4)
HAVING COUNT(itemId) > 1
```